# How do I convert multiple ASP.NET web forms apps using forms authentication (Membership) to point to a new .NET Core Identity site for their login

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

First, I want to apologize as this is my first post and I don't even know how to properly phrase my question.

Here's what's going on:

I have several legacy ASP.NET web forms applications (.NET Framework 4.6.1) built in VB.NET that currently use ASP.NET Membership provider and forms authentication. Basically, apps A, B and C redirect to a login screen on app D where the user logs in and then gets redirected back. I believe this is possible through forms authentication where all applications share the same machineKey in Web.config.

I created a new ASP.NET Core MVC application (.NET Core 3.1) using ASP.NET Identity to replace app D which in the future will also use IdentityServer4 to allow single-sign-in support for third-party clients. This new SSO app has new user screens to manage users/roles, etc. and is working great as a stand-alone site.

How do I get apps A, B and C to properly redirect to SSO so users can get authenticated and get redirected back?  What is the correct approach here?  What steps are required?

I spent weeks going through tutorials online, learning about IdentityServer4, creating new modern MVC sites that use OWIN to exchange tokens, etc. and that all works fine.  I also see tutorials on converting ASP.NET Membership to OWIN or to Identity but is that really what I need?  I have a new site that's already using Identity so I shouldn't right?

Ideas?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to to mix old ASP.NET applications with new IdentityServer, since they are very different architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. Using a new ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) - Visual Basic with .NET Framework 4.6.1 named VBWebApp, I did the following to get it connecting to my IdentityServer4 instance:

1. Install packages

   install-package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
   install-package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
   install-package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
2. Add Startup.vb

   Imports Microsoft.Owin.Extensions
   Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
   Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
   Imports Owin

   Public Class Startup
   Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
   Dim settings As NameValueCollection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

   ```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions With {
            .AuthenticationType = "cookie"
        })

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
            .SignInAsAuthenticationType = "cookie",
            .Authority = settings("Authority").ToString(),
            .ClientId = settings("ClientId").ToString(),
            .ClientSecret = settings("ClientSecret").ToString(),
            .RedirectUri = settings("RedirectUri").ToString(),
            .ResponseType = "code",
            .Scope = "openid profile",
            .RedeemCode = True
        })

        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)
    End Sub
   ```

   End Class
3. Add the following under Configuration tag in web.config
4. Add the following in system.web tag
5. Add the following in Config.cs in IdentityServer4 instance

   new Client
   {
   ClientId = "VBWebApp",
   ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
   AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
   RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44375" },
   PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44375" },
   AllowedScopes = new List
   {
   IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
   IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
   }
   }

Still more work ahead but at least now I have the steps required to get the authentication piece working for apps A, B, and C.